# How to remove Drupal Simpletest tables?

Tags: drupal-7, simpletest, drush

When I run my tests:

```
drush test-run
```

... and it finishes, I'm left with tons of tables in my database. Things like:

```
simpletest69123cache_menu
```

I know it creates these to run the tests, but when its done, how do I get rid of them?

**UPDATE**

Bonus question: Does setup run for each individual test? i.e. do modules and everything get enabled every time for each test? (this takes forever and I can't imagine this is how everyone uses the testing with Drupal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below command

**drush test-clean**

[Here](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x) is all command lists for Drush

You will be able to run the individual test. Example comamnd

**drush test-run --methods**

[Here](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/test/test-run) is the list for available test.

Answer (score 4):

In **Drupal 8** you can run the following command from the root of the web site:

`php core/scripts/run-tests.sh --clean`

For more information refer also to [Functional tests](https://docs.acquia.com/article/lesson-103-functional-tests) on Acquia's web site.